# Difference Between Aggregation Stream and Dashboard Total Calculation in Thingsboard

Tags: javascript, dashboard, thingsboard

I'm using an Aggregate Stream Node to calculate total production of the day and also using a Timeseries Barchart dashboard to represent that total.

- The key that is produced by the Aggregate Stream Node is being used in this custom dashboard inside the red circle.

[Custom Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqqCA.jpg)

- With this configuration

[Aggregate Stream Node configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqDbx.png)

- And in the Timeseries Barchart dashboard  I'm using the original key call "PPM2" (with the timestamp information) to represent the data with legend "Total" enabled.

[Barchart dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3j3q.png)

- The problem is I'm reporting different calculations between the Barchart dashboard and the Aggregate Stream Node.
- I been trying changing the node configurations but always have different results.

I will appreciate help or suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I also had issues with that node. Because of it, I made a combination of nodes with which I saved my values as attributes to summation and also kept the track of how many of those have I written down. On the end of the day, script had task to calculate the average and save it as a telemetry. I trust more to that then that Aggregate stream.

Comment: Thank's for your answer! Yes, I think I will use another method too because that node is not working as expected.